# Get a textNode as a childNode in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, text, internet-explorer-8

I have a reference to a `style` HTML tag with styling text inside of it. I'm trying to access this textNode through the `childNodes` property but it only returns an empty object. How can you access textNodes from their parent in IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text within the tags doesn't appear to be represented as a childNode in IE8. You can, however, access it as `.innerHTML` which returns all of the rules as plain text.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/F2Wcg/

Comment: That's what I did. It's very annoying that IE8 does this. Off the top of your head, can you think of any other tags for which this would also be the case (not including `script` tags)?

Comment: @JustinMeltzer I can't, off the top of my head. But if you run into this problem again in the future, you can always `console.dir(el)` and inspect which properties on the object have the value you're seeking. Then double-check to make sure those properties are standardized, or feature-test for them.